# Forcing dict keys to be used as argument specifiers with str.format

Tags: python, string, format

I have the following string interpolation:

```
>>> a = {'test1.1': 5}
>>> 'test: {test1.1}'.format(**a)
KeyError: 'test1'
```

It obviously fails because format is literally trying to access the object `test1` and its attribute `1`. Is there a way to format this string and force the key values to be taken as strings? (Looking for a Python 2 and 3 solution.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little hack, but this does the trick:

```
In [5]: 'test: {0[test1.1]}'.format(a)
Out[5]: 'test: 5'
```

Use dict-like indexing with `[..]`. The `0` is positional indexing, and `a` is the 0<sup>th</sup> argument. If it's the only argument, you can *omit* `0`.

Comment: Perfect! And to make it even nicer, I can pass the dict as a kwarg: `'test: {a[test1.1]}'.format(a=a)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just another alternative.  The old %-style formatting doesn't care:

```
>>> a = {'test1.1': 5}
>>> 'test: %(test1.1)s' % a
'test: 5'
```